# Can you apply BigQuery's PARSE_TIMESTAMP function to entire field?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a field "mytimestamp" which is currently of data type STRING, with the syntax "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss", and I'm looking to convert it in to a field of type TIMESTAMP. The function PARSE_TIMESTAMP works for a specific argument, eg

```
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', '15/04/2020 15:13:52') AS mynewtimestamp
```

but attempting to apply this to the entire column as follows

```
SELECT PARSE_DATETIME('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', mytimestamp) AS mynewtimestamp
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

yields instead the error "Failed to parse input string "mytimestamp""

Comment: Of course you can pass a column name in instead of a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have bad data in the column.  You can find the problems using:

```
select mytimestamp
from `project.dataset.table`
where SAFE.PARSE_DATETIME('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', mytimestamp) is null
```

Answer (score 0):

> yields instead the error "Failed to parse input string "mytimestamp""

Error message suggests that instead of passing `mytimestamp` as a column name - you are passing `"mytimestamp"` as a string - so check your query for this